# FragmentManager is already executing transactions after findNavController().popBackStack()

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a profile fragment that I manage with NavgitaionComponents bottomNavigationView, the thing is that from here I want to logout my user, I do this by doing this

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Glide.with(requireContext()).load(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.photoUrl).centerCrop().placeholder(GlideProgress.setupCircularProgress(requireContext())).into(profile_photo)
        txt_profile_name.text = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.displayName
        txt_email.text = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.email
        btn_signout.setOnClickListener {
            showSignOutProgress()
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(requireContext()).addOnSuccessListener {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                startActivity(Intent(requireContext(),MainActivity::class.java))
                findNavController().popBackStack()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                hideSignOutProgress()
            }
        }
    }
```

My MainActivity handles what navigation graph to go depending if the user is logged in or not, if is logged in it will go to the main_navigation graph and if not to the login_navigation graph

Now, when I start my mainacivity after succefully signed out, when I do findNacController().popBackStack() I expect the current profile fragment to pop and pop all the backstack fragments, so in my login fragment when I go back I cant return to my profile fragment

but this happends

> Unable to pause activity FragmentManager is already executing
>   transactions

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I needed to finish the whole activity containing the main navigation instead of just poping the profile fragment

added

```
requireActivity().finish()
```

instead of

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```